# Setting a value twice on 1 input click

Tags: javascript

Hello I working on a Siemens PLC web server. I'm trying to figure out how I can set a value to 1 and then wait 300ms and set it have to 0. Below is what my code looks like. The initial set to 1 works fine, but it never sets the value back to 0. So any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="">
          <input type="submit" value="Start" onClick="setvalst()" >
          <input type="hidden" id="startbtn" name="LOCAL START PB" value="">
</form>

<script>
        function setvalst(){
   document.getElementById('startbtn').value = 1
   setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('startbtn').value = 0   
     } , 300);
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: a) How can you tell? b) you do nothing to stop the form from being submitted and reloading the page.

Comment: Since you are doing nothing to stop the form submission in `setvalst`, form is going to be submitted with the current values. So the current value is `1` is being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Set the input submit to a button instead.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <button type="button" value="Start" onClick="setvalst()"> </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="startbtn" name="LOCAL START PB" value="">
</form>

<script>
    function setvalst(){
        document.getElementById('startbtn').value = 1
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('startbtn').value = 0   
            } , 300);
        }
</script>
```